# Calculating the sum of a matrix row in R

Tags: r, matrix, sum

How would I calculate the sum of a row in a simple matrix in R?

My matrix is:

```
                     circle.sentancing.group control.group
less.serious                              34          3690
more.serious.or.same                      27          4560
```

I want to calculate the sum of the row `less.serious`.  I have tried using `rowSums` but this gives me the sum of all rows and I need the sum of this row only for the next calculation.

NB: the columns and rows have been labelled using `rownames`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `sum`? Assuming your matrix is named "M", try:

```
sum(M["less.serious", ])
# [1] 3724
```

Basically, you can use `[` to extract the relevant rows or columns using the structure `[rowstoselect, columnstoselect]`. When you don't specify any columns, it selects all of them.

You can use the names of the rows or the index position. For instance, `M[1, ]` is the same as `M["less.serious", ]`.

Comment: Thank-you - and for the additional information on the use of [ to index specific values.

Comment: @Alison, no problem. Edited to make it clear that "M" is the name of the matrix. If this answered your question, do consider *accepting* it when you can :-)

Comment: @Anando Mahto, yes this is the answer and the clarification on M.  I'm new to this, how do I accept.your answer?

Comment: @Alison, see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) -- Basically you click on the empty green checkmark that should be to the left of my answer, underneath where the votes would be displayed.